# using ubuntu from a memory stick

Tags: ram, settings

When using Ubuntu from a memory stick is there any way to keep your settings and also not have to put in your wfi password each time?

Comment: As described above, one alternative is to make a **persistent live** Ubuntu system and another alternative is to make an **installed** system. - You can use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to make a persistent live system. - You can make a portable installed Ubuntu Server system according to [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692). After installation and starting the system, you can install a desktop environment and get standard Ubuntu Desktop or Lubuntu or another Ubuntu family flavour.